# How to save only fields that change in an ASP.NET MVP application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a form with about 25 fields. A few fields are listed below.

```
<div class="form-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormData.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormData.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormData.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormData.LastName)
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormData.MiddleInitial)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormData.MiddleInitial, new { @class = "small" })
</div>
```

I have a FormData object that stores the values for the form and is later synced with a Patient object if ModelState is valid. The patient is stored in the session.

```
patient.FirstName = formData.FirstName;
patient.LastName = formData.LastName;
patient.MiddleInitial = formData.MiddleInitial;
```

Currently, every time the data is posted, it is saving every field to the patient. Is there a way to only save items that have changed? Or to track changes here? I'd assume that would improve efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this for each field:

```
if( !patient.FirstName.Equals(formData.FirstName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
  patient.FirstName = formData.FirstName;
```

That won't improve efficiency much though. This is an easy way. The other way is to track changes using Javascript on client using onchage event for < input > element and other but that is even more difficult. The problem is that it takes time to program it and to maintain it later. The easiest way is to save not changed data with changed data. If there will be performance issues then you could make these changes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of truly achieving what you want is by using a third-party Javascript library, such as Knockout. That's basically because the server does not know when the user changes something in his browser, unless he 'submits' some data. To use KO.JS, you will need to convey the MVVM approach as well.

Then, you can do something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormData.LastName, new { data-bind="value: lastName"})
```

The JS code will look like:

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("FirstName", "LastName")); ​
```

Here is a nice example that uses Knockout to handle data as it is changed:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like Premature optimization - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization. Do not do that until you see there is some real performance penalty. I think you will hardly notice some difference if you only save items that have changed. Most probable you will make your code less readable.